# WPF MVVM binding positions of two UserControls, when one gets moved, the other reacts

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to build a diagram with nodes, pins and wires.
Lets pretend i only care about the wires and pins for now.

**Wire**

```
<Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" >
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="### HERE I NEED TO BIND TO PIN POSITION ###">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>
                                <BezierSegment Point1="100 100"
                                               Point2="100 50"
                                               Point3="300 200"/>
                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Take a look at the ***PathFigure***'s **StartPoint**, its a **Point** value which tells the Wire where to start from.

Now the pin is much simpler, its basically a **Thumb**(which allows easy dragging and dropping on the Canvas)

```
<UserControl x:Class="WireMvvm.Pin"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WireMvvm"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="10" d:DesignWidth="10">
<Thumb Background="Red">
</Thumb>
```

What i dont know how to do is to apply the MVVM pattern in this occasion and as the Pin moves, the StartPoint from the Wire should have the same location as the Pin, i for sure know how to do this normally with events and lots of code behind and don't think its bad at all but i like to explore more ways.

I also need to be able to serialize the diagram and add pins/wires at runtime(but thats not my question, just extra information because im not sure how MVVM works with runtime dynamic stuff)

Should i have models for the wire and pin separately, then viewmodels for both too? Im seriously lost, and tried watching lots of videos but i still struggle to apply this with my idea.

Comment: If you want to go the MVVM way, you need view-models for your objects. For now, we only see views. Create the model classes `Pin` and `Wire`, serialize them if you need, create view-models `PinViewModel` and `WireViewModel` and create `DataTemplate`s  that will describe the views of those view models. In the views, use two-way `Binding`s. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an items control with a canvas inside of it. That way you can bind properties you mention and use data templates for your items.

```
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="CanvasScroller" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl Name="ItemsContainer"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=CanvasBoardViewModel.BoardItems}" 
                  AllowDrop="True">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas x:Name="_canvas" IsItemsHost="True" Background="White" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding CurrentLocation.X}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding CurrentLocation.Y}"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Width}" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Height}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Your Data Templates could be something like this

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CanvasBoardItem}">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle>

            </Rectangle>
            <Thumb></Thumb>
            <Thumb></Thumb>
            <Thumb></Thumb>
        </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Your View Model would be something along these line

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<CanvasBoardItem> BoardItems { get; private set; }

    public ICommand SerializeDataCommand { get; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        //Set up command here
        //Set up board items here
    }
}
```

Canvas board item contains all of the stuff you want to bind to in the items template like height, width, connections and so on